# Should I say no to a testing job when I really want to do development?

Tags: career-development, careers

I am a fresher. I recently got a job in a fortune 500 company. During the interview, they never mentioned that it was for a testing role. It felt like they were recruiting for development. I've completed a Google Summer of Code. They were very interested in what I did during that internship which was development. But after joining the company, they have assigned me a testing job and I'm not allowed to apply for another role for at least 2 years according to company policy. I talked to the manager if they could reconsider and he said he talked to his manager and they said I fit this role better.

I love programming and development. My manager says that I'll find automated testing interesting since I like programming which is all fine but I hate testing. I've only worked for 2 days now and people have been saying its too short a time to judge but I've loved my time coding during my internship. That's why I wanted to work. I also have an admit from Illinois Institute of Technology for Fall 2015 to study MS- Computer Engineering. IIT-C is not a very good college so I wanted to work for a year or two and go to a good college for MS. But with testing that I don't want to do, I'm not sure what do you think? Since its just 2 days how do I quit? Will I be blacklisted from similar companies if I quit now?

Edit : Thank you for all the advice. To answer some of the questions, its blackbox testing, unit testing is being done by the developers, I've asked the manager and team lead they advised me to to seriuosly consider a career in testing. The comapny has a 2 months notice policy. They haven't paid for relocation. As for money for college, I will be studying on a loan, my parents are not going to be paying for it. 
I will continue to work here and try to search for a new job. I've also decided to apply for a visa so I can go to college if I choose since I'm an Indian. It's a 9 hr job. Travelling is 2 hours. I live with my grandparents so I have to help them with some house work. Leaving home is not an option. So realistically, I'll only have time for open source contributions I want to do during the weekend, which is fine.

Will there be any repercussions to leaving if I go to college? I won't mention it on my resume will a company still know?

Edit 2: I think testing my own code is good. I won't be able to write good code otherwise. I meanti don't like testing when I don't have access to the code. I have decided to pursue a masters for now. I definitely have a lot more to learn.  I studied electronics and instrumentation in bachelors so that's working against me. Getting a CS degree will help. In India we don't get to change our majors after we choose it once. I didn't know what I wanted at 17 whne I chose to study eie. So I'll get a CE degree that will hopefully give me better opportunities because they told me that I've been assigned to QA since I'm not a CS student. Not being CS, I'm not eligible to apply to most jobs I want to do so I'm going to study. Thanks for all the advice

Comment: Are you aware that things like unit testing may well be part of what most developers do?

Comment: Never quit a job before you have a new one.  If you don't like where you are at, put your resume back out and start interviewing - while still doing your testing job and collecting a check.

Comment: How badly do you need the money?  Do you have a trust fund, or indulgent parents who'll continue to support you?  This may come as a real shock, but lots of us wind up doing things we don't really like for a time, because we've gotten fond of eating and sleeping in beds rather than cardboard boxes.

Comment: `I like programming which is all fine but I hate testing` - Testing is a fundamental skill in programming. Anyway, if you don't like your current job then you should really find another position and then make a clean exit from the current one.

Answer (score 4):

I understand where your frustration come from, because I worked my way up from a QA tester to a software engineer myself.

***Short and overly simplistic answer:*** **Yes**, if development is what interest you the most.

***Long answer:*** Despite the fact that development work interest you the most, it does not give employers good impression if you quit your job now. As you mentioned yourself,

> I've only worked for 2 days now and people have been saying its too short a time to judge but I've loved my time coding during my internship.

Give them some more time to see what you are really capable of doing, and perhaps they'll change their mind in a year.

However, I suggest that you keep looking for new opportunities outside as well. Since you strongly express your interest in development, I think the earlier you start in a development role, the better. When considering a job offer, personally I believe that ***job security should be the least of all the concerns for a new grad. Instead, look for something that interest you the most.***

Having said that, from what I've heard most people would agree that staying at least 6 months prior switching to a new job is a reasonable thing to do. So don't forget to take this into consideration because it does reflect on your resume.

Answer (score 2):

If you really feel that this isn't for you, then start looking for a new job. But keep in mind that you have a job and you have no idea how long it will take to find a job. Keep working with this company until you find a replacement job.

Of course potential employers will wonder why you are looking when you have only been with the new company a few days. Tell them you though the position was as a developer, but it is really as a tester.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered the hard way, large companies love to hire swarms of new grads and stick them wherever they see fit. ;)

A few things to consider:
1) Are you contractually obligated? Did the company pay for your relocation? If so you'll be on the hook to repay those moving expenses should you leave within a certain period of time (usually 12 months, sometimes longer). Also be sure to check for any non-compete clauses. 
2) Think long term. The reality is sometimes you learn by doing and starting out in testing is a great way to see what doesn't work so that when you do get asked to develop something you'll get it right the first time. This is more true for SDET roles than QA roles. Also many companies appreciate developers who have a test background. 
3) Examine the networking and learning opportunities where you're at. One reason to go to work at a large company early in your career is to build a strong network and also to grow your skills at their expense. This can really pay off long-term. Also will this role help you get into a better school?
4) Who says you can only develop during work hours? Embrace side projects. At this stage in your career there's a good chance they'll be of more interest to your next employer than your current work projects. Side projects also demonstrate a degree of entrepreneurship which many companies like to see these days. 
5) 2 days is WAY too early to make any final decisions. Give it at least a month. Do make your aspirations/interests known to your manager. If they seem disinterested or indifferent then you should strongly consider moving on. An unsupportive manager at such an early stage in your career is disastrous.